# Install OS X 10.8 from bootable USB on empty Mac HDD

Tags: macos, mac, install

I have a bootable USB for 10.8, but my Mac's HDD is completely empty. How do I install this OS to my Mac?

Comment: You need to give us more details, when you say bootable USB do you mean it boots to an installer or it boots directly to a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the USB and hold alt on boot, then select the USB drive.